# How to print Google Drive folder name in the cell automatically by pasting the folder ID on adjacent cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-drive-api

How to print Google Drive folder name in the cell automatically by pasting the folder ID on adjacent cell in google app script on Google Sheets.

Suppose I have two cells A1 and B1, is it possible to get fetch or get the Google drive's folder name automatically on cell B1 when we paste the folder ID in cell A1? I wonder there might be a Google app script function which could make this possible. Please help me out in this case. I'd be glad if you could share the script.

I've crawled internet and didn't found any solution please help me out in this.

IMAGE ELABORATION:

[image]

```
function myFunction() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var folder_id = ss.getRange("Sheet1!B2").getValue(); // get value in "Settings!C9" 
    const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id);
    sh.getRange('E2').setValue(destinationFolder);
}
```

Comment: use app script to connect to your google drive account and do a file get it will return the name.

Comment: @DalmTo I'd be glad if you could just jot down the script, I've currently worked on blow script, its working but not the folder name is not showing automatically when the id is pasted. script is as under:

function myFunction() {


const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');


  var folder_id = ss.getRange("Sheet1!B2").getValue(); // get value in "Settings!C9"
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id);
 


sh.getRange('E2').setValue(destinationFolder); 

}

Comment: You need to use a trigger. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you will need to use a trigger to do this process. For this case, you will need to add a [trigger manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

[image]

Since the simple triggers do not work when they call Google Services. In this case the DriveApp services. This information can be found in this [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.